# Symfony 4 - VichUploader Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not allowed

Tags: php, file, symfony, serialization, vichuploaderbundle

I've a symfony 4 project with "FeuilleConge" entity (with VichUploader), and an User entity and a Absence entity with relation with "FeuilleConge" entity.

When I submit an Absence, I persist too the "FeuilleConge" on my User->getFeuilleConge().

But when I submit an Absence (with FeuilleConge entity), I've this error :

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not
>   allowed

I tried to add serialize() and unserialize() methods to my FeuilleConge and Absence entities, like this :

Absence.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AbsenceRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Absence
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\FeuilleConge", inversedBy="absences", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $feuilleConge;

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,

        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,

        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

}
```

FeuilleConge.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Serializable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\Uploadable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FeuilleCongeRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class FeuilleConge
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="feuilleCongeName", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $feuilleCongeName;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="feuillesConge", fileNameProperty="feuilleCongeName")
     * @var File
     */
    private $feuilleCongeFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="feuilleConge", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Absence", mappedBy="feuilleConge")
     */
    private $absences;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->absences = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @param File|UploadedFile $feuilleConge
     *
     * @return FeuilleConge
     */
    public function setFeuilleCongeFile(File $feuilleCongeFile = null)
    {
        $this->feuilleCongeFile = $feuilleCongeFile;

        if ($feuilleCongeFile) {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getFeuilleCongeFile()
    {
        return $this->feuilleCongeFile;
    }


    /**
     * Set urlPaquet
     *
     * @param string $urlPaquet
     *
     * @return FeuilleConge
     */
    public function setFeuilleCongeName($feuilleCongeName)
    {
        $this->feuilleCongeName = $feuilleCongeName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlPaquet
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getFeuilleCongeName()
    {
        return $this->feuilleCongeName;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return FeuilleConge
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        // set (or unset) the owning side of the relation if necessary
        $newFeuilleConge = $user === null ? null : $this;
        if ($newFeuilleConge !== $user->getFeuilleConge()) {
            $user->setFeuilleConge($newFeuilleConge);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Absence[]
     */
    public function getAbsences(): Collection
    {
        return $this->absences;
    }

    public function addAbsence(Absence $absence): self
    {
        if (!$this->absences->contains($absence)) {
            $this->absences[] = $absence;
            $absence->setFeuilleConge($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAbsence(Absence $absence): self
    {
        if ($this->absences->contains($absence)) {
            $this->absences->removeElement($absence);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($absence->getFeuilleConge() === $this) {
                $absence->setFeuilleConge(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->feuilleCongeName,

        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,

        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

I added same methods on my User entity.
But the problem is the same.

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add serialization methods on your User class, since your problem is due to Symfony trying to serialize it. Your Absence class is then serialized only because Symfony tries to serialize the entire User object (that you need to avoid)